# Redirect to route redux

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router

I use react-redux-router, and I try to make redirection. But I don't now how to do this correctly. Only solution what I know is dispatching "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE" event, but it seems to not correct. Is there better way to do redirection?

Comment: Apply `routerMiddleware` and use: `store.dispatch(push('/foo'))`. Via https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Answer (score 1):

A redirect when visiting a route can be done with the Redirect component; check https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect.

For a redirect in the app itself, check push() from react-router-redux (you seem to be using this library): https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward

Comment: Thank you so much!